# Eclipse Android Emulator not showing file browser to access sdcard

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to access the sdcard in Eclipse Android Emulator 4.0.3

I am looking for the file browser to access an sdcard, but the emulator is not showing it:

[image]

So I searched in DDMS->file explorer->mnt and I found sdcard there:

[image]

And `SD Card` support is shown in the AVD settings:

[image]

But still the emulator is not showing the file browser, thus I cannot access the sdcard.

How can I solve this problem?  Thanks!

Comment: For this you need to install any fileExplorer application to your emulator..